# Баг FireFox или нужен ли тег tbody?

Tags: html, firefox

Здравствуйте! Замечалось, что браузер Firefox изменяет код html, а именно добавляет тег `<tbody>` при использовании таблицы. Вопрос в том, стоит его самому писать или это баг firefox? Вроде firefox добавляет этот тег к каждой таблице без исключения. Я просто не вижу необходимости его добавления, разве что стили применить к нескольким ячейкам, но просто сам тег без атрибутов... Думаю, вопрос этот волнует не только меня. Хоть и мелочь но все же. Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тэг tbody добавляет не только ff, но и все другие браузеры (по крайней мере современные).
Данный тэг является обязательным. С оговоркой для таблиц без thead и tfoot, когда все строки представляют собой одну группу, при этом браузеры сами создают tbody, может быть во избежание (вдруг кто-то скриптом добавит футер, придется dom всей таблицы менять).

**N.B.** если в таблице у вас нет thead и tfoot, можете tbody не писать, браузер сам за вас построит dom верно. если есть thead и tfoot, то обязательно и tbody прописывать. в любом случае в dom'е будет tbody.

Answer (score 5):

Это все из-за W3-консорциума. Это они придумывают стандарты разметки, которые всякие браузеры повторяют. А бедный HTML-гуру потом ломает голову, зачем вообще нужны теги типа tbody, thead и tfoot. После таких измышлений многие профессионалы и вовсе отчаиваются и начинают верстать сайты в Word'е — он честный, и творит легко через «Сохранить как веб-страницу». Но это уже тонкости высшего пилотажа. А новички пусть и дальше страдают валидностью и соблюдением стандартов.

Comment: @Realetive__ :)

Comment: Плюсую за сарказм :)