# Не применяются стили bootstrap для класса .table-hover

Tags: css, jquery, bootstrap, vue.js

Всем привет. Есть проект на vue с компонентами(.vue). А так же для верстки используется bootstrap(обычный которому нужен jquery, не bootstrap-vue)

Есть проблема. В одном из компонентов описывается таблица с классом .table-hover этот класс должен подсвечивать строку в таблице(tr при наведении) и как я понимаю это реализовано на jquery. все компоненты от vue а так же все js скрипты необходимые для работы bootstrap'а собираются в один общий js файл. И есть проблема. Т.к. таблица с классом .table-hover подгружается с помощью vue после загрузки страницы, то я столкнулся с проблемой, что класс .table-hover не обрабатывает наведение на строку в таблице. Хотя если попробовать эту же таблицу возвращать не из vue, а сразу вставить в php страницу, то все ок и класс .table-hover работает нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли как нибудь сделать так, что бы после того как vue вставляет таблицу на страницу, jquery заново вешал все свои обработчики событий на такие классы как например .table-hover. К сожалению проект уже большой и живет долго и перенести его на bootstrap-vue нет возможности

Comment: Там вроде обычный bootsrap css: `.table-hover tbody tr:hover`. Вполне вероятно таблицу вы генерируете без `tbody`. Без кода сложно сказать.

Comment: @РустамГимранов Да простите затупил. Вот такой код. https://jsfiddle.net/841jd057/ На саму страницу компонент вставляется вот так: <app></app>. Дело в том, что если эту таблицу просто вставить в html страницу сразу, то .table-hover работает. Я думал дело в том, что если через VUE, то он возвращает html таблицы после того как jquery загрузился и повесил все свои события на .table-hover. но я не пойму как заставить jquery заново повесить свои события после того как vue отрендерил таблицу

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/139057/256824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсветка строк в таблице определено в `css` правиле `bootstrap` и никакого отношения к `jquery` не имеет:

```css
.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```

Зачем тут промежуточный `tbody`? Потому что теги `tr` могут быть вложены в теги `thead` и `tfoot`.

---

Браузер при парсинге DOM вставляет `tbody`, если тот не прописан явно. Если интересно, то смотрите [спецификацию](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#in-table-body). По всей видимости, в таблицу, сгенерированную через `javascript` браузер не вставляет тег `tbody` и вышеприведенное правило `css` не отрабатывает.

---

Наглядный пример, **без подключения `jquery`**: вторая таблица находится в компоненте `vuejs`.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

const App = {
  template: `
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered thead-light" id="pay_table">
  <tr><th>Имя</th><th>Покупка</th><th>Сумма</th><th></th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="X" id="del_pay"></td>
  </tr>
</table>`
}

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    App
  },
  template: `<app></app>`
})
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered thead-light" id="pay_table">
  <tr><th>Имя</th><th>Покупка</th><th>Сумма</th><th></th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="X" id="del_pay"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="app" v-cloak></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
```

---

**Очевидное решение**: начать прописывать `tbody` и считать его обязательным вложенным тегом в теге `table`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это и в правду помогло. Теперь всегда обязательно буду использовать thead и tbody :)