# webcomponent почему элемент выпал из потока?

Tags: javascript, css

Задача: организовать максимально простое программное добавление/удаление строк в таблицу.

Мне показалось хорошей идеей использовать для этой цели веб компоненты

Изучил следующие материалы:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices

https://habr.com/ru/post/346670/

Сделал template, зарегистрировал компонент.
Код:

```
<table >
  строки таблицы
  <row-event RER_time="16:31"></row-event>
</table>
```

https://codepen.io/ulibka68/pen/oNNwZKG

Сам webcomponent по задумке должен жить внутри таблицы и генерировать одну строку с отображением необходимых данных.

По факту получилось что webcomponent "выскочил" перед таблицей, хотя был в нее вставлен.

Подскажите пожалуйста как поправить код так, чтобы я мог генерировать строки с помощью webcomponent

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Вот на этой странице https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table после первой демки есть табличка голубенькая, в ней указан **Permitted content** (разрешенный контент). *Предположительно*, что все другие, непосредственно дочерние элементы, браузер будет выкидывать наружу, проглатывать и вести себя непредсказуемо.

Comment: Вероятно, что нужно делать по такому [принципу](https://github.com/mdn/web-components-examples/tree/master/editable-list), вот [демка](https://mdn.github.io/web-components-examples/editable-list/), а вот еще [примеры](https://github.com/mdn/web-components-examples). Собственно, если кто-то захочет, то может эти комментарии в ответ оформить.

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/989645/256824

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся со схожей проблемой. Судя по всему причина кроется в использовании shadowroot, не все теги можно в него закидывать.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow